# How to make CQWP retrieve 4 most recent Items in the whole site collection?

Tags: 2013, caml-query, content-query-web-part, query

I'm a little stuck with one of m Content Query Web Part:

On my homepage, I would like to display the 4 most recent items added to my site collection in a Content Query Web part called "What's new?"
So it could be from any content type (document, Custom Content type...)

So, I've added a cqwp on my home page, in the Query, I've selected "display elements from all sites of this site collection", let blank "List type", and let "`All Content Types`". in presentation, I've ordered by "`Created[_Hidden]`" (i have nothing else) and set the limitation to 4...

And yet, `nothing is displayed`, but all my elements are published. I don't understand.

Do you have any idea on **how to display the 4 most recent Elements of my site collection,**?

Comment: You don't happend to have Enterprise version and content search web part?

Comment: Nope, and that is a real pain : we have Standard version and CSWP is not available on it...